# Primes where fibonacci $\operatorname{mod} p$ cycles through all pairs

Tags: number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Show that when prime $p$ doesn't divide $x^2-x-1$ with any positive $x$, then the sequence $\operatorname{fib}(n)\pmod p$ contains all possible pairs in consecutive numbers except $(0,0)$.

For example with $p=2$ the sequence is $1,1,0,1$ which contains
$(1,1)$,$(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$

I found this in https://oeis.org/A086937 but I cannot find the proof.

Comment: I think I'd approach this by finding the period length of the Fibonacci sequence mod $p$.

Comment: [Here is an entry point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period#Number_theory) to proofs of this sort (take $k=1$ in that page for the usual Fibonacci numbers).